ngx-bootstrap Angular 18 compatible version
I tried to create Angular 18 application with ngx-bootstrap. But when I installed ngx-bootstrap, I'm getting dependency issue.
Whats the ngx-bootstrap compatible version for Angular 18
When Angular 18 compatible version will be available?

Same Issue here also. Whenever I am importing ModalModule.For Root () in appModule I am getting error on the terminal. The funny thing is even in their repository they are asked to install
ngx-bootstrap Angular Bootstrap CSS
13.x.x 18.x.x 5.x.x or 4.x.x
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

Sorry for inconvenience. Angular 18.0.0 compatible version is on it's way, should be available to you any time now!

See here -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap?activeTab=versions; 18. I used 18.1.3


Add this to your package.json file,

 "overrides": {
    "ngx-bootstrap": {
      "@angular/common": "$@angular/common",
      "@angular/core": "$@angular/core",
      "@angular/animations": "$@angular/animations",
      "@angular/forms": "$@angular/forms"
    }
  }


Run the npm install command again. Seems to have worked for me:

CMD: npm install ngx-bootstrap@12 bootstrap font-awesome
